# Cast object with mandatory property into object with same optional property

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying wrap my head around why the following doesn't work:

```
/* @flow */

type A = {
  foo: string
}

type B = {
  foo?: string
}

const a: A = { foo: 'bar' };
const b: B = (a: B);
```

Flow gives me:

```
12: const b: B = (a: B);
                  ^ Cannot cast `a` to `B` because string [1] is incompatible with undefined [2] in property `foo`.
References:
4:   foo: string          ^ [1]
8:   foo?: string           ^ [2]
```

All I'm trying to do is convert an object where a property is guaranteed to exist into an object where the property **might** exist - shouldn't that be ok?

[Try Flow link here](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgCCYAvGAN6phhRxwBcYAzhgE4CWAdgOaoC+6bPjAAhUhSo06AfkYsOPfugDGcTizABDRsTLkpDMAHIARptZGwfANypV6jGBOMxZABTbRASmtA) (no idea how long this will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's possible to write `null` or `undefined` to `b.foo`, you could do this:

```
b.foo = null
console.log(a.foo) // null
```

Clearly, we don't want a.foo to be null, so Flow warns us with the error you're experiencing. To prevent this error (and to satisfy Flow's typechecking), you can mark B's `foo` property as [read only](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-readonly) (also called "[covaiant](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only)") and then the assignment works (and we won't accidentally overwrite the `foo` prop).

Here's a bunch of examples of this in action:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoKUBmB7LAuKAzsAE4CWAdgOYoC+KKokUAQgsmpjgPz5FlW16AYyzkiUAIb44iJJzxQA5ACMJxRVBoBuegHpdUAKIAPCQFswAG2gBGfMyzAAFlGIQJAE1GWQKEWOAoZXwAEgAldw8AeXIfAB5mAD42AAopKHDImPikgEodFH0jUwtrKAAmfAApAFdxZVdI719-eoB9N09mtoxiLDM2gHcyYHdlazsMiM9skATkxAl6RmgYNuno2JA2VHQAamwFPgpKKCLa8WdoQ6gwPshiUChSAigRADc1UglyYEFCgwwSyBbDEMwEXAAqArWDrLJbNiZGZbOIwRJQrDEKEwtYbWaIvEo1BFdCHXgkE5QmjohjgaDMOHInw7DgHbjk-jUOhQkzmKzQADM+GUjhcnS8CIkgRhHggQksailpFEflE4gkHSaW2kjM2zMWqoCQU1XW1LF1+MWJolPgKRV5pWgABZ8BICARSJRyCdJFBhqRRhJxtAsMoAFZy6VYX3i5pQUQQQ3tWNbHp9Ab+wPByrmwn6yQFIA))

```
type A = {
  foo: string
}

type B = {
  foo?: string
}

const a: A = { foo: 'bar' };

// Example 1: Both readonly
const b: $ReadOnly<B> = (a: $ReadOnly<B>);

// Example 2: Just b readonly
const b_readonly_from_writeable1: $ReadOnly<B> = a

type A_ReadOnly = {
  +foo: string // Just the foo property is covariant
}

// Alt forms:
// type A_ReadOnly = $ReadOnly<A>
// or
// type A_ReadOnly = $ReadOnly<{
//   foo: string
// }>

type B_ReadOnly = {
  +foo?: string
}

// Example 3: both readonly at type declaration
const a_readonly: A_ReadOnly = a
const b_readonly: B_ReadOnly = a_readonly;

// Example 4: assigning a writeable object to a readonly one
const b_readonly_from_writeable2: B_ReadOnly = a;
```